Rcpp C++ binary object not found when adding a new function to an old R package
I am running the latest R and Rcpp under MacOS Sonoma.  I am attempting to add a new function call C++ code to a very old package (Hmisc), setting things up using Rcpp::compileAttributes().  The new R function's .Call() to the C++ binary object results in object not found.  Here's what I have in place:

DESCRIPTION: Imports: Rcpp and LinkingTo: Rcpp
NAMESPACE: export('pMedian') and useDynLib(Hmisc, .registration=TRUE, .fixes='F_')

.fixes='F_' handles old Fortran binary objects in the package


src/init.c: several references to the old Fortran routines, nothing about the new C++ routine
src/RcppExports.cpp: (RcppExports.o also present), contents:

// Generated by using Rcpp::compileAttributes() -> do not edit by hand
// Generator token: 10BE3573-1514-4C36-9D1C-5A225CD40393

#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

#ifdef RCPP_USE_GLOBAL_ROSTREAM
Rcpp::Rostream<true>&  Rcpp::Rcout = Rcpp::Rcpp_cout_get();
Rcpp::Rostream<false>& Rcpp::Rcerr = Rcpp::Rcpp_cerr_get();
#endif

// hlqest
double hlqest(NumericVector x);
RcppExport SEXP _Hmisc_hlqest(SEXP xSEXP) {
BEGIN_RCPP
    Rcpp::RObject rcpp_result_gen;
    Rcpp::RNGScope rcpp_rngScope_gen;
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< NumericVector >::type x(xSEXP);
    rcpp_result_gen = Rcpp::wrap(hlqest(x));
    return rcpp_result_gen;
END_RCPP
}


src/hlqest.cpp: has all the recommended code including // [[Rcpp::export]], and the hlqest function runs fine in an interactive session in which the .cpp code is loaded using Rcpp::sourceCpp.  hlqest.o is also there.
R/RcppExports.R: contains the following and the resulting R function runs fine interactively as mentioned above

hlqest <- function(x) {
    .Call(`_Hmisc_hlqest`, x)
}


R/pMedian.r which contains the following

#' Pseudomedian
#'
#' Uses fast C++ code from the `DescTools` package to compute the pseudomedian of a numeric vector.  The pseudomedian is the median of all possible midpoints of two different observations.  The C++ code is originally from Monahan and Moser.  The pseudomedian is also called the Hodges-Lehmann one-sample estimator.
#' @title pMedian
#' @param x a numeric vector
#' @param na.rm set to `TRUE` to exclude `NA`s before computing the pseudomedian
#'
#' @return a scalar numeric value
#' @export
#' @md
#' @seealso <https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/1271.319414>, <https://www4.stat.ncsu.edu/~monahan/jul10>
#' @examples
#' x <- 1:5
#' pMedian(x)
#' # Compare with brute force calculation and with wilcox.test
#' median(outer(x, x, '+')) / 2
#' wilcox.test(x, conf.int=TRUE)

pMedian <- function(x, na.rm = FALSE) {
  if(na.rm) x <- x[! is.na(x)]
  n <- length(x)
  if(n == 0) return(NA_real_)
  if(n == 1) return(as.double(x))
  .Call(`_Hmisc_hlqest`, x)
}

After building the binary Hmisc package and loading the package I get the following error upon running pMedian(1:5): Error in pMedian(1:5) : object '_Hmisc_hlqest' not found.  Any help is appreciated.

The idea is to put // [[Rcpp::export]] above your function hlquest.
What RcppExports.cpp and RcppExports.R then do is to ensure you can an R-callable hlquest(x) -- as that is easier / simpler than the expression you show above, namely
.Call(`_Hmisc_hlqest`, x)

One or two more other things to pay attention to is that the NAMESPACE has a line
useDynLib("Hmisc", .registration=TRUE)

as the .Call above does not pass a string and does not reference the package. (And you show you have that, which is something I missed on my first read.)
I have also found that adding to an existing package is hardest in the sense that for a 'new' package without an src/init.c the corresponding entries are automatically created in RcppExports.cpp but if I remember correct the compileAttributes() call is careful and will not modify an existing init.c.   So it is finicky -- but one you dot all i-s and cross all t-s it should work.
And as you write

src/init.c: several references to the old Fortran routines, nothing about the new C++ routine

it might be best to check with a throw-away one-function package you can create what would be needed and to then add that manually to your existing src/init.c.

Thanks for the excellent advice Ada.  I fixed the simple things, capitalizing on hlqest() (which didn't fix the main problem) and next will follow your great advice to create a new package with only this new function in it.  I do have the Rcpp::export in the right place in hlqest.cpp.  NAMESPACE has useDynLib but with the .fixes argument added for the old Fortran modules.

Sounds like a good plan.  There does not seem to be a way to 'merge' the components of an init.c and what compileAttributes() creates for you. You could try (temporarily) renaming init.c and check if all of its content gets rewritten but of course the C++ tooling may not know about Fortran.

Neat idea, but compileAttributes() did not create init.c when I renamed the old one.  I tried my hand at editing the existing init.c by adding hlqest-containing lines but when installing the package I get "symbol not found in flat namespace: _hlqest".  Note that C code I use in the Hmisc package has do_functionname syntax in init.c but Rcpp is set up in the hlqest.cpp file to not use the do_ prefix so I omitted that in init.c.

compileAttributes() does not create init.c but places the equivalent content into RcppExports.cpp.  The devil is of course in the mixing.  If you have an existing package, and C code, and Fortran code, then the automation from Rcpp may not help so you may have to work it out manually.

Thanks Ada.  The RcppExports.cpp file, which currently is the same as the one listed at the top, looks quite reasonable, but perhaps init.c that handles Fortran routines is causing RcppExports.cpp to be ignored.  I'll proceed with your idea of creating a one-function package.
